# How to expand.grid specific objects in a list to form a new list

Tags: r, list

I have a list data as follows:

```
a<-list(10,c(8,9),5,14,c(3,7),c(2,3),5,13,c(3,4),4,5,8,12,c(2,3),c(5,7))
```

> a

[[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 10

[[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgUvm.png)]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 8 9

[[3]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 5

[[4]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 14

[[5]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 3 7

[[6]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 2 3

[[7]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 5

[[8]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 13

[[9]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 3 4

[[10]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 4

[[11]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 5

[[12]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 8

[[13]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 12

[[14]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 2 3

[[15]]
[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBPN.png)] 5 7

Then I want to use "expand.grid" in every 3 objects in list a.
That is to say, to expand.grid 1-3, 4-6, 7-9, 10-12, 13-15, respectively, then combine these result to a new list form.

Result should be something like following appearance.

[image]

I just use the foolishest way to solve this problem:`list(expand.grid(a[1:3]),expand.grid(a[4:6]),expand.grid(a[7:9]),expand.grid(a[10:12]),expand.grid(a[13:15]))`

When I try to use "sapply": `sapply(1:(length(a)/3), function(x){expand.grid(a[1:3+3*x-3])})`it didn't work, the result is as follows:

[image]

I don't know why, and could you help me with this problem, thank you so much!

Comment: if your list is a multiple of three... `lapply(as.data.frame(matrix(a, 3)), expand.grid )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a grouping index with `gl`, `split` the sequence of 'a', subset the `list` elements using the index and use `expand.grid`.

```
lapply(split(seq_along(a), as.numeric(gl(length(a), 3, length(a)))),
                         function(i) expand.grid(a[i]))
```

We can also use `sapply`, but make sure we use `simplify=FALSE` as the option

The OP's code with `simplify=FALSE` gives

```
 sapply(1:(length(a)/3), function(x)
       {expand.grid(a[1:3+3*x-3])}, simplify=FALSE)
```

According to `?sapply`

> simplify: logical or character string; should the result be simplified
>   to a vector, matrix or higher dimensional array if possible? For
>   sapply it must be named and not abbreviated. The default value, TRUE,
>   returns a vector or matrix if appropriate, whereas if simplify =
>   "array" the result may be an array of “rank” (=length(dim(.))) one
>   higher than the result of FUN(X[[i]]).

Comment: That's nice! Thank you so much! O(∩_∩)O

Comment: You are great! Thanks!